# La información encriptada en CryptoJS no desencripta

Tags: javascript

Estoy encriptando un *JSON* donde tal escriptado lo guardo en una base de datos pero si cojo el encriptado y voy a desencriptarlo con la contraseña en vez de mostrar la información me muestra una serie de números.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```js
var string_private = {

"name": "juan",
"city": "New York",
"age": "18"

};

var password_private = "ejemplo@ejemplo.com+PRUEBA2022";

//var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(string_private), password_private);

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt("U2FsdGVkX19nWCdce0VE4oxE28OEzRFuPbIWMDr2LFnOtnX892eyO8n79OtvXojOV3RVj8XiAjLgMTK40YDUxw==", password_private);

document.write(decrypted);


// RESULTADO
// 7b226e616d65223a226a75616e222c2263697479223a224e657720596f726b222c22616765223a223138227d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo mira espero te pueda ayudar, te hacía falta agregar un toString() al finalizar el encriptado y tambien faltaba parsear el resultado a JSON, espero te sea de ayuda:

```
import CryptoJS from "crypto-js"

const string_private = {
"name": "juan",
"city": "New York",
"age": "18"
};

let password_private = "ejemplo@ejemplo.com+PRUEBA2022";

let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(string_private), password_private).toString();

let decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, password_private);
let decryptedData = JSON.parse(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));

console.log(decryptedData);
```

Corrijo mi respuesta.